# Does it makes sense to bind XML to a class in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I have 4 different types of XML (no XSD as of now) as input to my Java program.

my goal is to process them and insert into DB using proprietary API's accordingly

I was wondering if it makes sense to bind these XML to Classes and then process.

In the past I am used to simply read the xml using a parser and do the job. I want to explore other alternatives, it's advantages & disadvantages for better learning

thanks

Note: I am not from Java background but pretty much have programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) is the standard way to do this, see other answer, it's already included in the JDK.

Advantages

- maps types for you, no need to parse integers etc.
- handles collections like lists etc.
- you need to write a schema (could also be seen as a disadvantage)
- business logic processing the XML is decoupled from parsing logic

Disadvantages

- you need to write a schema
- one object per element node might be too heavy if you have tight memory constraints/very large files, in that case consider [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is JAXB Unmarshalling. See this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)